# Bookreader: installing books using separate applications

Tags: android, reader

I'm developing bookreader, which has it's own book format. I want to have separate application for reader itself and books. So user firstly installs bookreader via Google Play, then installs books, that lives in Google Play as separate applications.

So, my question is:
1. How can I make application without launch icon (book)? Maybe using intent filters?
2. How can I distribute books inside application and then open them using main (reader) application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered contributing to the open source Coolreader or FBreader? Last I checked the search facilities on Windows were useless on both, and out of development for many years. But I suppose Android devices at least can overlook that. It's off topic for SO for me to say it but the idea does not sound auspicious.

From a SE POV distributing your content with your application sounds like a waste of creating your own book format (which is what I urge you not to do). Parsing SGML content is fraught as it is and you will only be told to use standard library SAX and XML parsers.

I don't understand your first question, "1. How can I make application without launch icon (book)?". Perhaps you would be willing to rephrase that.

In the meantime I hope you can make some sense from what else I have written.

UPDATE_ after comment

That's what I half expected, although I still don't understand your first question. Essentially it is an application more than a one way viewing of media. I'd suggest looking at the Inkle engine behind Steve Jackson's Sorcery series and 80days.

There are infinetly many ways to go about this. At least with a bookreader as you initially wanted the options were limited. I suggest my favourite interactive book reader, Inkle, but this post is now hopelessly off topic.

Comment: Ok, let me exxplain what I want. It's not just simple books like pdf or fb2. It's books with tests, interactive lessons etc. So I can't just use current book formats. Also, it's not my own project, it's commercial one. We have publishing house, they what own book reader and publish their books as book for own bookreader. Books itself is made already (it's htmls, JSes etc.). Also we already made reader for desktop.